# Limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ using power series of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, power-series

Suppose we want to find $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. 
Moreover, we know that $f(x)$ has a power series expension for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ 
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
\end{align}
and we have a nice closed expression for all $a_n$'s.

My question can we compute $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ based on the knowledge of $a_n$'s?

**Case 1:** If $a_n \ge 0$ then 
\begin{align}
f(x) \ge a_0+a_1x
\end{align}

so

\begin{align}
 \lim_{ n\to \infty} f(x)= \infty. 
\end{align}

**Case 2:**  An interesting case which I would like to understand is when $a_n$'s have alternating sign and $|a_{n+1}| \ge |a_n|$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the power series have infinite radius of convergence, then?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, the functions is analytic on all $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Being analytic on all $\mathbb R$ is not the same as having infinite radius of convergence. For example $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is analytic on all $\mathbb R$, but the power series $1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$ has radius of convergence $1$.

Comment: @Sure. The function has infinite radius of convergence.  I had in mind this definition: A function f defined on some open subset U of R or C is called analytic if it is locally given by a convergent power series.

Comment: But the point is "analytic on $\mathbb R$" is not the same as "infinite radius of convergence".

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I agree, I misspoke.  In the question I posted,  we should assume that $f$ has an infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: Note that if $a_n> 0$ for all $n,$ then $f(x) \to \infty.$

Comment: @zhw what if the coeffiecients are alternating and $|a_{n+1}| \ge |a_n|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a very delicate question; take for example $f(x)=\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k+1}$ and $g(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k}$. Then $f$ ad $g$ have both infinite radius of convergence and very similar coefficients, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ doesn't exist, while $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$. So it seems that its difficult to directly tell something about the limit solely by considering the sequence of coefficients, without calculating $f$ (and thereby the limit) explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. What about integration? Can we say if the function is integrable if we know all of the coefficients?